# Changing a php variable with html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the value of a php variable when the user clicks a html li element which has been generated using php. I am not getting an error but it doesn't appear that the variable is changing. Is there something wrong with the below code? Note it is inside a php file within php tags. Thanks.

```
$testvalue = "a";
echo '<li onClick="'.$testvalue.' = \''."b".'\' ">test</li>';
```

Edit:
I fixed it! Super happy. I was able to use javascript to parse the variable where I needed it before the php function was called. Thanks for the help guys...or girls (probably not :) )

Comment: Try using Javascript, or reading up on HTML Forms.

Comment: You cant do that.

Well you could.

Call javascript to ajax the php change.

Do you want the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.

PHP code is executed server-side.  Your `onclick` function is executed client-side.  In other words, by the time the user clicks on this `<li>` element, the PHP code has completed execution.

You can, however, try using AJAX to make your JavaScript interact with your server, depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was afraid this may be a problem.